# Pascal's triangle and derivative

Tags: derivatives, binomial-coefficients

$$1\\
1 \quad 1 \\  
1 \quad 2 \quad 1  \\
1 \quad 3 \quad 3 \quad 1 \\
1 \quad 4 \quad 6 \quad 4 \quad 1 \\
\\$$
I've seen a video which was showing a derivative trick in such a way as to make it easier. Consider the pascal's triangle as shown below. On the condition that we have to find $(x^5 e^x )'''$, which is the third derivative, we'll be using these coefficients $1-  4 - 6 -4-1$ and taking derivatives of the first function.

$$x^5 + \color{blue}4\times 5x^4 + \color{blue}6\times 20x^3 + \color{blue}4\times 60x^2+120x$$

Finally, I'll multiply by the derivative of $e^x$ and start from the right.

$$\underbrace{x^5}_{e^x} + 4\times \underbrace{5x^4}_{e^x} + 6\times \underbrace{20x^3}_{e^x} + 4\times \underbrace{60x^2}_{e^x}+\underbrace{120x}_{ e^x}$$

Which yields after factoring

$$e^x(x^5+20x^4+120x^3+240x^2+120x)$$

What if it was $(\cos(x) e^x + \sin(x))'''$? I could have used the same strategy for $\cos(x) e^x$. However, I don't know how to handle $+\sin x $ because it's not product.

Regards

Comment: This looks like Leibniz's formula for the $n$-th derivative.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Let me take a look at Leibniz's formula. It seems to be confusing.

Comment: It's like Binomial theorem, but for derivatives of functions instead of powers of numbers. [Here's wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Comment: @Adam However, there are several things make me confused. For instance, $(\cos(x) e^x + \sin(x))'''$ and $(\cos(x) tan(x) + \sin(x)\cot(x))'''$ I don't know how to apply this rule for those derivatives.

Comment: Derivative is linear so $(f+g)^{(n)}=f^{(n)}+g^{(n)}$. Then you use the formula for $\cos(x)e^x$. For $(\cos(x)\tan(x)+\sin(x)\cot(x))'''$ you can just simplify $\cos(x)\tan(x)$ and $\sin(x)\cot(x)$

Comment: @Adam That looks ravishing! What about $\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan x}$? Is it $\sin x \dfrac{1}{\tan x}$?

Comment: $\sin(x)\cdot\frac{1}{\tan(x)} = \sin(x) \cdot \cot(x) =\sin(x) \cdot \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \cos(x) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the [sum rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation) repeatedly to obtain

$$
(\mathrm e^x\cos x + \sin x)'''=(\mathrm e^x\cos x)''' + (\sin x)'''\;.
$$